# Spring find 2 candidates, but there is only one

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying upgrade a JHipster project, however I found the following issue:

```
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.cervaki.config.AsyncConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- jhipster-io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties: defined in null
- io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties: defined in null
Action:
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

What I understood is that spring can't inject the correct bean because there are two candidates, but I only have the io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties implementation:

```
package com.cervaki.config;

import io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor;
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncConfiguration.class);

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    public AsyncConfiguration(JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        log.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getCorePoolSize());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getMaxPoolSize());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(jHipsterProperties.getAsync().getQueueCapacity());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("cervaki-Executor-");
        return new ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

You can download the pom.xml [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpyfcqhz9peb8d9/pom.xml?dl=0).

I did a search in the entire code and libs to find the jhipster-io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties file, however I didn't find anything.
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share you pom/build gradle and the imports?

Comment: @juanlumn I shared the pom.xml and added the imports, as you requested

Comment: Upgrading from which version to which version? Have you run mvnw clean?

Comment: Trying to update from 2.23.0 to 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue after generating new JhipsterApp, 
And as you - I don't find the "jhipster-io" dependencies in project
How I solve this:

1. in `src/main/java/your/package/config` create a "AppConfiguration.java"
2. with content:

   ```
   import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

   @Configuration 
   public class AppConfiguration {

       @Bean
       @Primary
       public JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties() {
           return new JHipsterProperties();
       }
   }
   ```

**even without** @Primary - I haven't got this error